# Вдогонку о дефисах

Tags: языкознание

И сразу по ходу возник еще один вопрос: а к какому разделу языкознания относится постановка дефисов? Это пунктуация или все-таки орфография? А то я не знала, какой тег ставить.
Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Слитное, раздельное и полуслитное (дефисное) написание регулируется правилами орфографии.

Comment: Пожалуй, единственный вариант, который рассматривается в обоих разделах, - это выбор формы написания приложений: кузнец Архип и  Архип-кузнец (выбор раздельного или слитного написания)  и Архип, кузнец (обособление со значением уточнения).